# Slide the slider on click event (Slick Slider)

Tags: jquery, html, css, slider, slick.js

I am new in jquery. I am using a custom cursor and want to move the slider on click event now if the cursor is in left side of slider on click event it should slide on left side (to the previous slide) and if the cursor is in right side of slider on click it should slide on right side (to the next slide).

Currently it only moves in one direction i.e. in right direction.
here is my jquery code.

```
 $("#slider-arrow").mousemove(function(e){

    var z = $("#slider-arrow").width();
    var x = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;

    if( x >= z/2){

        $(this).css({ cursor : 'url(<?php echo base_url('/assets/images/icon-next.png')?>), auto'})

        .click(function () {

                    $("#slider-arrow").slick('slickNext');

            });
    }else if( x <= z/2){

        $(this).css({ cursor : 'url(<?php echo base_url('/assets/images/icon-open-prev.png')?>), auto'})

        .click(function () {

                   $("#slider-arrow").slick('slickPrev');

        });
    }

});
```

Comment: I have no idea about your html code but guess if you have #slider-arrow and #slider-arrow1 you should give both a class and write above code for the class .slider-arrow instead of one of them isn't right?

Comment: I have tried with the same class but result is still same !

Comment: can you provide html code here?

Comment: `code` <div class="home-slider" id="slider-arrow" >      
            <div >
                <img src="url"  alt="img" >
                <div class="header-overlay"> </div>           
             </div>
        </div>

Answer (score 0):

you used `$("#slider-arrow").mousemove(...` according to provided html code the `#slider-arrow` is your slider div and consider e.pageX gives you the place of mouse in the `#slider-arrow` division so you don't need to subtract the offset I think.

Comment: Ok but thats not the issue 
What i really want is to move the slider on next slide if the cursor click on right side and move to previous slide if the cursor click on left side......